# Why is KenoUI's RequireJS brining so many extra files?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs

I am following the Telerik guidelines put forth on [**Using Kendo UI with RequireJS**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-requirejs).  However, as whole bunch of "extra" files are being downloaded.  Neither the master, nor the page itself is accidentally linking-in the scripts from other areas...so something must be wrong with my `Require Config`.  But, I do not see it.

I am at a bit of a loss here...any ideas?

**THESE SCRIPTS ARE BROUGHT-IN ATOP THE MASTER MVC LAYOUT:**
So none of these are missing...

```
@Scripts.Render(@Model.PathCdnMicrosoft + "modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js")
@Scripts.Render(@Model.PathJQueryVersion + ".js")
@Scripts.Render(@Model.PathRequireJs + "/require.min.js")
```

**THE REQUIRE-CONFIG LOOKS LIKE**:

```
require.config({
        paths:
        {
              'jquery': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery//jquery-2.1.0.min'
            , 'jquery.validate': 'http://weblocal.refinedknowledge.esdev.com/ProjectName/Scripts/lib/jquery.validate'
            , 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': 'http://weblocal.refinedknowledge.esdev.com/ProjectName/Scripts/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive'
            , domReady: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady//2.0.1/domReady'
            , 'nc-scripts': 'http://local.mywebsite.com/ProjectName/Scripts/app/nc-scripts.js'
            , 'local.libraries.system': 'http://weblocal.refinedknowledge.esdev.com/ProjectName/Scripts/app/system/2013.4.1122.1/system'
            , 'kendoui': 'http://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2014.2.903/js'
        },
        shim:
            {
                  'jquery': { exports: 'jQuery' }
                , 'jquery.validate': { deps: ['jquery'] }
                , 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': { deps: ['jquery', 'jquery.validate'] }
                , 'local.libraries.system': { deps: ['jquery'] }
                , 'nc-scripts': { deps: ['jquery'] }
            }
    });
```

**THE REQUIRE LOOKS LIKE**:

```
require(['local.libraries.system', 'domReady', 'kendoui/kendo.multiselect.min', 'kendoui/kendo.grid.min', 'nc-scripts', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'],
    function (system, domReady) {

        domReady(function () {
        });
    });
```

**THE NET TAB LOOKS LIKE**:
I am only trying to bring-in the MultiSelect and the Grid.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at those two minified files you circled to see what their dependencies are?  It's quite possible the highlighted files are simply transitive dependencies of those modules, and that kendo's minified version is *only* minified, not concatenated (both would be preferable).

Comment: Good point...looking now

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are dependencies of the grid. You may be able to get rid of a few of those dependencies depending on which features you use (e.g. you don't need kendo.filtermenu.js if you use `filterable: false` or kendo.window.js if you don't use popup editing).

Telerik is maintaining a list of dependencies [for the grid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom#grid) and [for the multiselect control](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom#multiselect).